# Que significa esta declaracion de variable

Tags: java, netbeans

Esta es una duda que la llevo mucho tiempo teniendo, llevo programando 1 año en Java, pero aun no me queda claro lo siguiente.
Supongamos que tengo 2 clases sencillas

```
       public class Automovil{
    String patente;
    String modelo;
    int capEstanque;
}
```

Y la otra

```
Public class Menu{
Automovil auto;
}
```

Yo se que para instanciar objetos, se usa el =new clase(), pero en este caso, en la clase Menu, si lo dejo tal cual, esa variable `auto` que puede hacer? Puede guardar datos? o no sirve de nada?

Comment: Esa variable ahí es *miembro* de la clase y la puedes usar en cualquier método de la misma.

Comment: Ok, que significa que sea _miembro_ de una clase? que sea atributo de la clase Menu?

Answer (score 0):

La clase automóvil es un objeto que encapsula información relativa a vehículos, la declaras como atributo de la clase Menu, si puede almacenar información pero tendrás que asignarle un valor a los atributos de ese objeto, ya sea en el constructor de la clase Menu, al inicializarla, o en alguno de los métodos de la propia clase Menu.

Comment: He ahi mi duda, por ejemplo, cuando en los String, uno hace String x="texto"; String es un objeto y uno le da valores con el =, sin hacer new String(), entonces en este caso, la variable auto, que puede hacer sin estar instanciado?

Comment: Para los tipos String, Integer, Float y demás, comunmente conocidos como wrapers de tipos primitivos, el operador "=" está sobrecargado, de manera que ahcer String x = "Texto" es lo mismo que hacer 'String x = new String("Texto")'

Answer (score 0):

La variable Auto como la.tienes solo está siendo referenciada, pero aún no tiene ningún valor. 
Puedes asignarla más tarde en tu programa pero debes instanciarla primero teniendo su constructor

//Código

```
Automovil auto;  //Así sola no hace nada
```

// Código

```
auto=new Automovil(valor1,valor2,...); //Ya tiene un valor y la puedes ocupar
```